# Collect selected test strings in HTML page via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, csv

In a HTML page, I want to collect the text strings that a user has selected into an array which can then be exported to a CSV file.

So far, I have come up with the following JavaScript to collect the selected text strings into a global variable:

```
var $labels = [];

function getSelText() {

    if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) // FireFox
    {
    txt = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) // IE 6/7
    {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    } else return;
    if (txt != '') {
    $labels.push(txt);
    }

    document.aform.selectedtext.value = $labels.toString();
}
```

I use the following HTML snippet to test it:

```
<input type="button" value="Get selection" onmousedown="getSelText()">
<form name=aform>
    <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
</form>
<p>   
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

See also the following JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mhzrP/

The issue with the above code is that even when selecting different text strings and adding them to the array, each entry of the array seems to be the same.

I would appreciate some help on what is going wrong. Also, if somebody has some hints on producing a CSV file from the array, I would highly appreciate this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, tested and it works:

```
    var $labels = [];

function getSelText() {

    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) // FireFox
    {
        txt = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) // IE 6/7
    {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    } else return;
    if (txt != '') {
        $labels.push(txt.toString());
    }

    document.aform.selectedtext.value = $labels;
```

Agree with @Blacksheep code. add .join() to $labels.

```
document.aform.selectedtext.value = $labels.join();
```